# Closing files in python with opened with enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this code snippet to open files from a list of filenames called input_files.

Do I need to close the file explicitly using a finally: block, if so how ?

```
def read_file():
    try:
        for filename in input_files:
            for line_num, line in enumerate(open(filename, encoding="utf-8"),1):
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line:
                    # do something with line and line_num
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        print("File not found")
    # finally:
        # file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `with open() as f` to reliably close the file, even if an exception happened:

```
def read_file():
    try:
        for filename in input_files:
            with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    if line:
                        # do something with line and line_num
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        print("File not found")
```

Comment: Or saving an indentation level by separating the logic of opening the file and iterating over its content (as demonstrated in my answer), at the cost of storing the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep processing other files in case of an exception you should change the try/except, by using *with* the file gets closed automatically:

```
def read_file():
    for filename in input_files:
        try:
            with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    if line:
                        # do something with line and line_num
        except FileNotFoundError as err:
           print("File not found", filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much less messy if you open the file in a dedicated `with` block then iterate over the file's content:

```
for filename in input_files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_content = f.readlines()
    for line_num, line in enumerate(file_content, 1):
        # do whatever
```

This code is more readable and lets Python deal with closing the file for you. However, this comes at the cost of storing the entire file in memory.

An alternative is shown in Nils Werner's answer, where the logic of opening the file and iterating over it is combined, at the cost of an indentation level.

Comment: Just curious, but do you mean " this is less messy" in terms of readability by saving an indentation level ?

Comment: @jpal Not only because of the indentation level, but also because then each piece of code has its purpose

Comment: slurping a file is a bad general recommendation. it should only ever really be done if you know that the size of the file is bounded. This type of optimization saves a tab of code depth in exchange for taking your server down at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closing` from `contextlib`. Your code becomes:

```
from contextlib import closing

def read_file():
    try:
        for filename in input_files:
            with closing(open(filename, encoding="utf-8")) as f:
                for line_num, line in enumerate(f,1):
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    if line:
                        # do something with line and line_num
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        print("File not found")
```

Comment: much better to simply use `with(open..)`

Comment: Yes, `open()` supports context management protocol so closing isn't necessary in this case. If op wants to use other type of open function without the context protocol, `closing()` will work even in this case.